# @RestController: Validate the @ResponseBody (not the @RequestBody)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can I achive that the @ResponseBody (in my case a class of type SomePojoInterface) is automatically validated (lets say through JSR-303 validation). Nice to have would be, that in case of a validation-failure the handler would throw an `Exception` which can be handled in some `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class.

My code so far.

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "validate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody 
    protected SomePojo validateResponse() {
        return new SomePojo();
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.XXX)
    @ExceptionHandler(MyResponseValidationException.class)
    public void handleResponseValidationException() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class SomePojo implements SomePojoInterface {

    @NotNull
    private String someValue;

    // getter / setter
}
```

Comment: Did you try it with some example? Something like this https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/. In Spring 3.2 you are able to add @Valid annotation ;)

Comment: So where should I put the @Valid annotation? I'm tring to validate the response object.

Comment: Oh it is for response! Then you have to create validator. I will post anser

Comment: You don't trust your own data?

Comment: Our data for the responses come from multiple foreign systems and are consolidated on our side. So, no I don't trust the data. I mainly want to log when I'm sending out invalid data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this through the `@RestControllerAdvice`.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestPostProcessingAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<SomePojoInterface> {

    @Inject
    private Validator validator;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        if(doSomeChecksIfEligiable(returnType, converterType)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public SomePojoInterface beforeBodyWrite(SomePojoInterface body, MethodParameter returnType,
            MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
            ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(body);
        if(constraintViolations.size() > 0) {
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.XXX);
            LOG.fatal("Sorry, I'm sending crap");
        }

        return body;
    }
}
```

Be aware that throwing an `Exception` and catching it in an `@ExceptionHandler` that is sending the same (mofified) object out in the `@ResponseBody` could lead to an endless loop, since the object will be checked again this `@RestControllerAdvice`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have annotated your class SomePojo, then:

```
     @GetMapping(value = "validate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        protected SomePojo validateResponse() {
           ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
           Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

           SomePojo somePojo = new SomePojo(null);

          Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(somePojo);
          // Other stuff
        }
```

@Valid annotation is for request. More examples from their [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-obtaining-validator). I am not sure what all you want to validate

Comment: as stated @Valid is used for the request, since the backed didn't create it. Since the backed creates the respones, it can hopefully be created so it is not invalid (class invariant)

Comment: @Hrabosh, I know how to validate. I was referring to some handler that I could trigger in some phase to do this 'in the background'.

Comment: @user871611 Then I dont know. I know it by `@Valid` for request, but for response I dont know other way then this which I answered, sorry :(